# Running Powershell script via Runspace from C# is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, powershell

When executing a particular script from Powershell command window, the execution takes about 2 minutes. Executing the same script from C# (Windows Service) using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces takes 5 to 6 minutes! Spawning new powershell.exe process from the service makes time drop to 2 minutes again.

I also noticed the CPU usage is higher when using Runspace.

Unsurprisingly, nearly all the time is spent in Pipeline.Invoke(), which doesn't make debugging the problem any easier.

The script I use is complex and does whole bunch of stuff, thus it's not easy to pin down the issue. How can I narrow down the problem?

Is there something obvious I may be missing?

Comment: I use System.Management.Automation.Runspaces a lot and never see such a performance loss. From the top of my head: is this the case that your script actually produces huge number of errors when it is run in the default or custom host associated with a runspace? Default/custom host may have something not implemented which may cause errors. Errors not necessarily stop processing but may affect performance.

Comment: runspaces are common to both methods - the difference I see is the security context. powershell.exe obviously runs as you, and the service will run as the service account (assuming it's not you.) Is this an AD or other issue?

Comment: @RomanKuzmin Perfmon shows there is initially few peaks of exceptions (about 900 total!), however after few seconds there are no more. Don't think that is the cause of my problem. Still, how can I find when those exceptions reported by perfmon are thrown? 900 looks like an awful lot!

Comment: @x0n I have tried changing service user to the same (administrative) account as for the command window, or running powershell.exe with -noprofile. That didn't help...

Comment: @ya23, I was talking about PS errors, they are not always correspond to classic exceptions. Inspect the content of the system variable $Error in the end of your script (e.g. dump it to a file). If you do not see anything, OK, this possible cause is eliminated. But if you see something it may give you further ideas.

Comment: Is the concerned PowerShell script signed? In that case you might already lose some time prior your script is actually running...

Comment: Have you tried setting up any trace logging? That's usually helpful, especially between pipeline invocations. Also, are you taking advantage of the pipeline? Is there a lot of pipelining, or not very much at all? I'm pretty sure that each pipeline steps gets it's own thread for dispatching work.